# Reference Error: 'data' is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Hello guys and thank you for reading this,

today I ran into the problem that I'd like to submit a html form via ajax but it seems that the data inside this form isn't passed on to jquery.

My setup is as following:

I have to use `var jq = $.noConflict();` to prevent conflicts of prototype and jquery (so `jq` just means `$`).

index.php - includes another .php page (`content/pc-service.php`) via `jq('#p2-content').load('content/pc-service.php');`

content/pc-service.php - looks like this:

```
<script>
    jq(function () {

        jq('form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            jq.ajax({
                type: jq(this).attr("method"),
                url: jq(this).attr("action"),
                data: jq(this).serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    jq('#p2-content').html(data);
                    //alert('success');  // <-- this alert - when uncommented - actually fires on clicking submit!
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
<?php

if(!sizeof($_POST))
{

?>

[... some texts and stuff]

<form action="?p=pc-service" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" value="hello" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>

<?php

}
elseif (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

?>

[... content that should be displayed on submit]

<?php

}

?>
```

So when I press submit and the alert is uncommented, as stated above, it gives me an alert but when I try to display the data inside a `<div>`  this is my result in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Please tell me where I'm wrong and thank you all for helping me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not include the parameter in your `success` handler function:

```
success: function (data) { // < add 'data' here
    jq('#p2-content').html(data);
}
```

Comment: I'll do so once I can (10 mins) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parameter here,

```
success: function (_**PARAMETER**_) {
    jq('#p2-content').html(data);
    //alert('success');  
    // <-- this alert - when uncommented - actually fires on clicking submit!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing success parameter,

```
success: function (data) {
    jq('#p2-content').html(data);
    //alert('success');  
    // <-- this alert - when uncommented - actually fires on clicking submit!
}
```